# Gradle error Failed to resolve: com.github.Binary-Finery:Bungee:master-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android, gradle

**

### Each time there is a problem: Failed to resolve.

**

Please help to understand this problem.
Thank you in advance .

> Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.github.Binary-Finery:Bungee:master-SNAPSHOT Show in File
> Show in Project Structure
>   dialog

Build Graldle App:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mkurbanov.lebap_kwartira"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.13.1'
    // for experimental rx picker
    compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:1.13.1'
    // If you have a problem with Glide, please use the same Glide version or simply open an issue
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.Binary-Finery:Bungee:master-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add in project level gradle.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}}
```